# Detect mined blocks by specific nodes

Tags: go-ethereum, mining, json-rpc

Using `web3` to connect to a `geth`'s node rpc API, is there a way to detect when a block has been mined by a specific node? The only way I've found so far is to redirect the node's console output to a file and parse that file. Is there a better way?

FYI - All the nodes are mining to the same public address so I can't use the `miner` property of a block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it is to let each miner set their own 'extraData' field, as described in the [documentation](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Command-Line-Options):

```
--extradata value         Block extra data set by the miner (default = client version)
```

This can be quickly shown by typing

```
web3.eth.getBlock('latest').extraData
```

on geth console.

Note: the output is in hexadecimal format, which can be converted into readable format with

```
web3.toAscii(web3.eth.getBlock('latest').extraData)
```

Comment: Yeah, I have discovered that option a few hours ago. I'll give it a try, but the miner I'm using is actually a fork of `geth` supporting a different blockchain implementation. I'm not sure they will honor this configuration. If not do you have any other idea? How does the miner knows when it mined a block successfully? I'd like to tap directly into that process if possible. Could I spy on the peers connection traffic to check if the miner tried to broadcast a block?

Comment: Hmm...detecting block broadcast is likely to be messy: what happens when a block is orphaned, or becomes an uncle?

Comment: I confirmed that it works with the other blockchain, thanks. Also, any idea how to put a public address in there? I'm limited by the 32 chars limit. I've worked around the limit by converting to base64, but I'm sure there's a better way?